# Is Xamarin Master-Detail Template Broken When used with Azure Backing?

Tags: web-services, xamarin, master-detail, project-template

The Master-Detail template in Xamarin has typically been a great starting point for many of my apps that work with .Net Core Backing Service. For review it has a Dependency service in the Client that allows Mocking of the Azure Backing Service or connection to a real or local service while in development.

The control variable generated by the template is  `public static bool UseMockDataStore = true;`

All Code discussed is completely found here: https://github.com/BicycleMark/SignalRGB

I created a Xamarin Master-Detail project naming it SignalRGB and  did the following:

1. The solution project structure looks like:
   [image: Solution Explored Visual Studio 2019]
2. I start Instance **one** Visual Studio 2019 And Run SignalRGB.Web
   [image]

3) Made Note of url: [https://localhost:44300]
4) Opened another Instance of Visual Studio (2) to run client with `UseMockDataSource=false` / The default it displayed results in Client using `MockDataSource`

5)went to these lines and updated Client for talking to my local server waiting for an http request :

> ```
>  public static string AzureBackendUrl =
>             //DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android ? "http://10.0.2.2:5000" : "http://localhost:44300";
>             DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android ? "http://localhost:44300" : "http://localhost:44300";
>         public static bool UseMockDataStore = false;
>         public App()
>         {
>             InitializeComponent();
>             if (UseMockDataStore)
>             {
>                 DependencyService.Register<MockDataStore>();
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 DependencyService.Register<AzureDataStore>();
>             }
>             MainPage = new MainPage();
>         }
> ```

6. Went and ran SignalRGB.UWP from VS Instance(2) and client application hung on the line GetStringAsync():

   ```
        bool IsConnected => Connectivity.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet;
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Item>> GetItemsAsync(bool forceRefresh = false)
        {
            if (forceRefresh && IsConnected)
            {
                var json = await client.GetStringAsync ($"api/item");
                items = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Item>>(json));
            }

            return items;
        }
   ```

I have tried other platforms iOS and get same result:

What Am I doing wrong here?

Comment: have you tried using the IP instead of localhost?  I don't know about UWP but usually that causes problems with iOS and Android

Comment: Went to command line: (1) ipConfig yielded  192.168.77.113 (2) ping  192.168.77.113 succeeded (3) Ran Server project it showed browser correctly https://localhost:44300/api/item (4) replaced with  https://192.168.77.113:44300/api/item  Browser returned 'Bad Request'

Comment: do you have your server setup to work with remote requests?

Comment: I am doing this all locally. I run one instance of Visual studio pressing run button 'IISExpress' in VS 2019 toolbar

Comment: All the source code is available here https://github.com/BicycleMark/SignalRGB

Comment: I have tried turning Win 10 firewall off in settings. No luck there too :(

Answer (score 0):

Oversight? in the templated code perhaps.  44300 is the port but notice the protocol.

DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android ? "http**s**://localhost:44300" :

Comment: Hey Patrick: Thanks for your attempt. I have now put your attempt on the list of thisngs i tried which did not work. The source is up there. If you pull it down maybe we could determine if it is just my system...